# Solving a heat equation problem

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, heat-equation

I'm brand new to Mathematica. I am trying to solve a heat equation problem, but I keep getting back the input on the output line.

The problem:

> Consider the equation
>
> $\qquad u_t = u_{xx} - 9 u_x$, $0\lt x\lt1 , t\gt0$,
>
> with boundary condition $u(0,t) = 0 ,\ u(1,t) = 0$
>
> and initial condition
>
> $u(x,0) = e^{4.5x}\!\left(5\sin\!\left(\pi\,x\right)+9\sin\!\left(2\,\pi\,x\right)+2\sin\!\left(3\,\pi\,x\right)\right)$.
>
> Solve for $u(x,t)$

My try at the code:

```
heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - 9*D[u[x, t], x]; 
ic = 
  {u[x, 0] == E^(4.5x)*(5 Sin[Pi*x] + 9 Sin[2*Pi*x] + 2 Sin[3*Pi*x]), 
   u[0,t] == 0, u[1,t] == 0};
sol = DSolveValue[{heqn, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

The output is just a simplified version of my input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing is that you need square brackets for Sin, for example `Sin[Pi x]`

Comment: @MelaGo Adding square brackets still gives me back the input

Comment: never use real numbers when using exact solvers like `DSolve` and `Solve` and `Integrate`, etc.. This is the first rule of thumb I learned using Mathematica long time ago.

Comment: Note that in Mathematica 12.1, the OP's code computes just fine.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - 9*D[u[x, t], x];
ic = {u[x, 0] == E^(9 x/2)*(5 Sin[Pi*x] + 9 Sin[2*Pi*x] + 2 Sin[3*Pi*x]),
   u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0};

sol[x_, t_] = DSolveValue[{heqn, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}] //
  FullSimplify

(* E^(-(9/4) ((9 + 4 π^2) t - 2 x)) (5 E^(8 π^2 t) Sin[π x] + 
   9 E^(5 π^2 t) Sin[2 π x] + 2 Sin[3 π x]) *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
{heqn, ic} /. u -> sol // Simplify

(* {True, {True, True, True}} *)
```

Plotting the solution,

```
Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.15},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"x", "t", "sol"}),
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Limit[sol[x, t], t -> Infinity]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Funny, the only modification here is `4.5 -> 9/2`?

Answer (score 5):

This finds a solution very quickly.

```
uF =
  NDSolveValue[
    {D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - 9*D[u[x, t], x], 
     u[x, 0] == E^(4.5 x) (5 Sin[Pi x] + 9 Sin[2 Pi x] + 2 Sin[3 Pi x]),
     u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0},
    u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

and gives the following plot:

```
Plot3D[uF[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @CA1998. I have made major corrections to the code.